# I get an error when i try to add a new point into my ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I get an error when i try to add a new point into my ArrayList
Here is my coder i don t get it why there is an error.

here is my Point class

```
public class Point {

public int X;
public int Y;

public Point(int X, int Y) {
    this.X = X;
    this.Y = Y;

}

public int getX() {
    return X;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    X = X;
}

public int getY() {
    return Y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    Y = y;
}


// Field-Area to be Colored
public Point Color_Field(Point a) {

    Point fieldAreaColor= new Point(0, 0);

    fieldAreaColor.setX(a.getX() + 5);
    fieldAreaColor.setX(a.getY() + 5);

    return fieldAreaColor;
}

}
```

and here is my List Class weher i try to put new points into my 
list. which doesn t works.

```
package Handler;

import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import Basic_Geom.Point;
public class Liste {


    ArrayList<Point> points=new ArrayList<Point>();

    points.add(new Point(2,3)); //here is my error i can t add a point to my list.


}
```

Comment: Please explain what your error is and provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than your full code.

Comment: First, read the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A statement such as `points.add(new Point(2,3));` must be inside some method/constructor.